# Need a professional in ubuntu to help me in how to run silkroad like those ppl?

Tags: 12.04

I'm new to Ubuntu, I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64.

I could not play Silkroad online, so i asked Google and I found that there's application named Wine, and I found some commands to run in the Terminal, to install it.

I did all that successfully.

Then I tried to start the game, via wine, and I got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYip8.png).

Now I don't know what I should do. On Youtube I saw players that can play Silkroad on Ubuntu without problems.

---

Check this out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vY8AK8M43EQ

Commands I used to install wine:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

Comment: Looks like there's a dependency on something called NetEngine, were there any steps you had to take on windows to get it to run? Also, did you install silkroad from a cd or did you download the installed files?

Comment: I understand that you *have* installed them, but *how*? was it a cd or download?

Comment: i didn't install it brother i've the game already installed on my pen drive and i moved em to the new /home partition after creating and installing ubuntu. please help me :'(

Comment: Install NetEngine again.  The underlying software isnt installed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reinstall it. This is because most software depends on other programs and utilities for it to run; in this case NetEngine. When you install software, the installation utility usually ensures that all dependencies are met so the software will run. Clearly you've copied the Silkroad program & its files, but haven't copied the NetEngine software.

Installing it again will ensure it runs.

Comment: Omg Thanks guys <3 i'll try and say what happend